# Codeship Pro build step with aws-deployment does not produce any meaningful output

Tags: codeship

Hello everyone who knows how Codeship Pro works :). I'm trying to deploy my application to AWS ElasticBeanstalk with "codeship/aws-deployment:latest". It works fine on my local box (checked with jet), but on Codeship the build step fails with no meaningful output. All it reports is

```
2017-01-25T06:24:48.493Z awsdeployment build/pull started 
2017-01-25T06:24:48.555Z awsdeployment build/pull finished successfully
```

Service configuration is:

```
awsdeployment: 
  image: codeship/aws-deployment:latest 
  encrypted_env_file: deployment.env.encrypted 
  volumes: 
  - ./:/deploy 
  working_dir: /deploy
```

Build step configuration:

```
- name: deploy_someapp
  service: awsdeployment 
  command: codeship_aws eb_deploy ./somedir someapp someapp somebucket
```

Am I doing something wrong or there is some specific in "aws-deployment" container output that does not allow codeship display it? Maybe there is a way to make codeship more verbose?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from conversation with Codeship dev team it became clear that:

1. I generated `codeship.aes` locally with jet and then encrypted env file with it. But in Codeship I have another, production AES Key which must have been used instead. So I downloaded correct AES Key and re-encrypted my env file.
2. Lack of output details is due to a bug on Codeship side and they are currently working on it. Hopefully soon more logs will be available :). Thanks Codeship team!